# Changing font and color of a text

Tags: html, css

Instead of creating a whole other id and ruleset, why can’t I just put multiple values (ex. font-family: cursive; color: blue) in a single ruleset? I tried it and it works and seems like a quicker way to do it. For example, if I want to change the font, color, and uppercase/lowercase of a title, can't I just put all those values into one ruleset?

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way to do this is using *Cascading Style Sheet (CSS)*. This allows you to edit the visual aspects of the site without having to deal much with the HTML code itself.

Explanation :

```
<[tag] style="[css]"> Content </[tag]>
```

Where `[tag]` can be anything. For example "p" (paragraph), "span", "div", "ul", "li".. etc.

and where [css] is any valid CSS. For example "color:red; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold"

The recommended way to add style to a html element is by assigning it a "class" (a identifier that can be repeated on the document) or a "id" a unique identifier that shall not be repeated in the document.

**For example:**

```
<[tag] id="element1" class="red"> Content </[tag]>
<[tag] id="element2" class="red"> Content </[tag]>
```

Where tag is any html valid tag. id is a unique arbitrary name and class is an arbitrary name that can be repeated.

Then in the CSS (inside the tags of your document):

```
<style type="text/css">

.red {
    color:red;
}

#element1 {
    background-color:black;
}

</style>
```

For this example and to keep it simple to new users I named the class "red". However class="red" isn't the best example of how to name . Better to name CSS classes after their semantic meaning, rather than the style(s) they implement. So class="error" or class="highlight" might be more appropriate. ( Thanks to Grant Wagner for pointing that out )

For a complete guide to CSS you can visit this link: http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Remember:

Keep your HTML Code clean and use CSS to modify ANY visual style that's needed. CSS is really powerful and it'll save you a lot of time.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please checkmark and upvote  it so it can help the community!

Comment: @ATLA Fan, did my answer help you, or do you still have a problem? If it helped you, please remember to checkmark it so it can help the community.

Comment: Hey @ATLA Fan, I checked your profile and it said you were active daily. I am wondering if my answer that I posted over a month ago has helped you, if it has can you please upvote so it can help the community?

Comment: Has my answer helped you? I posted it over 4 months ago

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can and it’s okay to do that.

Actually this is the right way!

so you create a ruleset with a specific selector, then you write all the properties that you wish and element to have (if the selector applies to the element)